# AWS SQS queue not triggering Matillion job

Tags: amazon-sqs, matillion

I have an SQS queue that receives a message with the file name that has been created in a target bucket. The process to send the message is:

1. csv file is inserted into `target_bucket`.
2. A message is sent to an SNS topic.
3. The SNS topic triggers a lambda function, and this lambda function posts a message into an SQS queue that includes the name of the file that was just created.
4. To check is messages are arriving to my queue, I do a simple poll from the console.

I know all the components are working just fine because by polling from the AWS Web console I can see the messages. This is an example:

[image]

However, the intention is to connect this SQS queue to Matillion so every time a new file is uploaded into my `target_bucket` a job is executed. This job should read the data from the new file and load it into an SnowFlake table.

I have connected my SQS queue to my Matillion project but every time I load a new file into my `target_bucket` nothing happens. Here are the project configurations needed for SQS:

I know my queue has access to Matillion because as you can see from the final cell, I have a ***success*** message when testing the connection.

[image]

Also, I added an environment variable (from Project > Manage Environment Variables) called `file_to_load`:
[image]

And finally, in the S3 Load component (from my job), I also added the `file_to_load` in the **pattern** section as shown in the image below:
[image]

Comment: Do you get any relevant information from your catalina.out (a.k.a. the Server Log)? SQS messages that can't be parsed will be silently consumed, with an error in the logfile. Although the message body in your screenshot does look OK to me.
Secondly, try turning on the Failure Queue? If it's something like the Project Name is mis-spelled, you will get a failure SQS explaining the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!

In the S3 Load component there is a parameter called `S3 Object Prefix`. Since I am providing the full path of the files (within the bucket), then the `S3 Object Prefix` should only have the S3 URI of the bucket name, for example:

- `S3 Object Prefix`: `s3://{bucket_name}/`
- `Pattern`: `file/path/name.csv` (received in `file_to_load` variable from SQS)